# Tomcat -Xms -Xmx not behaving as expected

Tags: java, tomcat

I have 32GB Ram in my system, and I want to test the behavior of -Xms and -Xmx, so I have set

```
set CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms13312m -Xmx15360m
```

in setenv.bat file inside the Tomcat 10.1.10 bin folder to increase initial memory to 13Gb and maximum 15Gb.

[image]

After starting Tomcat, I never see the memory starting from 13Gb, it's using around 4Gb.

[image]

I am not able to understand its behavior. Can we control exact minimum and maximum RAM allocation using this or some other settings irrespective of application demand?

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask] and check if you've declared `-Xms` twice.

Comment: Memory allocation in an OS is generally more complicated than this. IIRC (but I'm not 100% sure), the Memory column in Task Manager shows actual physical memory that is allocated to the process. When you started Java, it might have allocated 15GB of virtual memory, but it doesn't mean it is actively using it, so the OS might have swapped it out, or because of accounting of memory, as long as the program hasn't touched it yet, it is isn't counted towards its memory use.

Comment: In other words, Task manager is not a memory profiling tool. If you want to be confident about your measurements, use a tool that is actually made to make those measurements.

Answer (score 0):

Windows resource monitor show this memory data in a proper way , Task Manager only shows the Physical memory in use , Not the Reserved Virtual memory , Total -Xmx allocation comes under Reserved Virtual memory then it allocate to Physical as demanded by application.